# In wordpress how to get all pages by a specific author?

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to get all pages(not posts) published by a specific author in wordpress, what is the php code to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have the ID it's possible to query using WP_Query object. If you don't have the ID you can find it also by email, or other means.

Don't forget to reset the global `$post` variable pointer to the beginning of the loop using `wp_reset_postdata()`

```
$username = "username";
$meail = "what@ever.com";
$user = get_user_by('login', $username);
// $user = get_user_by('email', $email);
$user_id = $user->ID;

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'posts_per_page' => -1, // -1 to retrieve all pages
    'author' => $user_id,
);

$posts = new WP_Query($args);

while ($posts->have_posts()) {
    $posts->the_post();
    echo ('<h1>' . get_the_title() . '</h1>');
}
wp_reset_postdata();
```